# Swift 4 - Is there is way to set Avenir font for all button and labels present in Project or App delegate file

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

Is there is way to set Avenir font for all button and labels present in Project or App delegate file. I want a common place where i can set the font once so that it changes in all storyboards. how can i do this ?

Comment: Create custom `UIButton` and `UILabel` subclasses, for which you set the font, then make all your buttons/labels inherit from your custom classes.

Comment: where can i set the font in custom classess. problem in the custom classes is setting the font require sizes and size of button will vary from pages to pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For `UILabel` you can solve this problem with `UIAppearance`

`UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)!`

And for `UIButton` it's not as simple as with `UILabel`, but you can always use inheritance

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override var titleLabel: UILabel?  {
        get {
            let label = super.titleLabel
            label?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)!
            return label
        }
    }
}
```